# Receiving "RunTime Error 70" when changing value in Combobox on Userform

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, userform

I am hoping someone can help. I have a list of which you have duplicate values in 1 column and in the column to the right unique values. I am wanting to create it so that if the `Me.TBR = "ALL"` then `Me.CBC.RowSource = BNme`, if I switch and `Me.TBR <> "ALL"` then it looks at what is in the column with duplicate values and only brings in what matches is in `Me.TBR`.

The code works when I select this from a fresh `Userform` session, so if I select `ALL` it gives the `Rowsource = "BNme"` having to `Unload Me` and Re open the `Userform` again and selecting a `value <> "ALL"` it loads all the correct information. However, if I am still in the same session and in the dropdown for `Me.TBR` I switch from `"ALL"` to another value. I get a Run Time error 70 an debug for the line `Me.CBC.List = arrBDat`

Please see below my code. Hoping someone can help.

```
Dim arrCDat As Variant
Dim arrBDat As Variant
Dim mysearch As String
Dim cnt As Long
Dim idx As Long
Dim Searchrange As Range

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Me.TBDS = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.CBRS.Value, Sheet2.Range("MLookup"), 2, 0)
    Me.TBCC = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.TBDS.Value, Sheet2.Range("CCLookup"), 2, 0)
    Me.TBR = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.CBRS.Value, Sheet2.Range("A:C"), 3, 0)
    
If Me.TBR = "ALL" Then
    Me.CBC.RowSource = "BNme"
Else
    If Me.TBR = "MT" Then
        Me.CBC.RowSource = "MT"
        Else
        If Me.TBR.ListIndex <> -1 Then
            mysearch = Me.TBR.Value
    
        With Sheets("Lookups")
            Set Searchrange = Sheets("Lookups").Range("T2", .Range("T" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        End With
    
        arrCDat = Searchrange.Resize(, 3).Value
    
        ReDim arrBDat(1 To UBound(arrCDat, 1))
        
        For idx = LBound(arrCDat, 1) To UBound(arrCDat, 1)
            If arrCDat(idx, 1) = mysearch Then
                Me.CBC = arrCDat(idx, 2)
                cnt = cnt + 1
                arrBDat(cnt) = arrCDat(idx, 2)
            End If
        Next idx
        
        If cnt > 0 Then
            ReDim Preserve arrBDat(1 To cnt) 
            Me.CBC.List = arrBDat 'line receiving debug
        Else
            MsgBox "Uh oh, things have gone a little sideways and the LO " & mysearch & " cannot be located. Please try another Option!"
        End If
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Comment: If you are going to switch to using List to populate the combobix you need to clear the RowSource property, i.e. set it to "".

Comment: @norie many thanks. So simple